# Why Tab bar item icon is not center on iPad devices?

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, interface-builder, uitabbar

This is on iPhone:

I drew a red line to determine center of image based on the segue way line.
It's correct and Image will be center.

[image: iPhone Tabbar]

But on iPad the icon will be push to left and the image icon is not center anymore:
[image: iPad Tabbar]

Runtime sample:

The image is not center

[image: iPad tabbar]

Comment: Layout maybe not exactly in Interface Builder. Check this in Simulator or real device.

Comment: Same issue on real iPad.

Comment: Are got same issue

Answer (score 0):

Run in real device if not run in simulator. In Xcode sometimes layout may not adjusted properly. That's why it's looking like this. No problem, don't worry. If you want proper layout in storyboard for iPad, My suggestion is select iPad Pro 9.7 then select iPad Pro 10.5. Noe it can adjust properly.

Comment: It doesn't make different to running on real device, on simulator or in the interface builder. are all the same.

Comment: Try once again with new view controller and tab bar controller